# How to render HTML from RMarkdown without javascript in output

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

Even the simplest rmarkdown document when rendered seems to create an html document that includes javascript.  I am looking to create html that can be the body of an email.  Is there a way to render markdown with no javascript in the resulting html?

There is nothing special about the following, it is just a generic example:

````
---
title: "Sample"
author: "JKGrain"
date: "March 31, 2015"
output: html_document
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for     authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

The resulting html source begins like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />

<meta name="author" content="JKGrain" />

<meta name="date" content="2015-03-31" />

<title>Sample</title>

<script src="data:application/x-javascript,%2F%2A%21%20jQuery%20v1%2E11.....
```

Obviously, i have clipped the rest of the html, but hopefully this explains the issue.

Comment: @rawr - I tried your suggestion, and the resulting html still contains javascript.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The javascript in the default html output format comes from the theme, syntax highlighting, and mathjax for equations. You can disable these three things in the header like so:

```
---
output: 
    html_document:
        theme: null
        highlight: null
        mathjax: null
---
```

Comment: to help others who might have this same question, I will point out that indentation and the placement of colons is very unforgiving in the YAML.  If your options are not working as expected check those.

Comment: Thank you for this. 715KB down to sub 1KB. Given that I just wanted the R output to be generated (going into wordpress) this is perfect.