# Knitr generating very large html files

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am trying to use Knitr to write simple text-only html pages, but the file sizes are extremely large - 700KB for a 1 line RMarkdown.  I am on R 3.4.0, and R Studio 1.0.143

For example, the following RMarkdown file generates a 695 kb file.  When I look at the source, that is because there is a huge amount of base 64 code under the script tag.  Is there anything that can be done to make the file size more compact, say a couple of KBs that I would expect it to be

(eg script src="data:application/x-javascript;base64,LyohIGpRdW...and this goes on and on forever)

```
---
title: "This is  a test"
author: "Mukul Pareek"
date: "June 7, 2017"
output: html_document
---


## This is a test file which when knit to html is 695KB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My ad-hoc solution is to use the `BiocStyle` style from Bioconductor. This reduces the html file size to 50 kb.

```
---
title: "This is  a test"
author: "Mukul Pareek"
date: "June 7, 2017"
output: 
  BiocStyle::html_document
---
```

A more extreme solution is found here: [How to render HTML from RMarkdown without javascript in output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370306/how-to-render-html-from-rmarkdown-without-javascript-in-output)

It produces an html file smaller than 1 kb.

```
---
title: "This is  a test"
author: "Mukul Pareek"
date: "June 7, 2017"
output: 
  html_document:
    theme: null
    highlight: null
    mathjax: null
---
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  The second suggestion did the job for me - I wanted just a barebones html file.  Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 7):

The key to reduce the HTML file size is to set `theme: null`, which means to get rid of the giant Twitter Bootstrap styles. Below are a few examples:

```
---
title: "This is  a test"
author: "Mukul Pareek"
date: "June 7, 2017"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: null
  html_vignette: default
  prettydoc::html_pretty: default
---


## This is a test file which when knit to html is 695KB
```

`html_document(theme = NULL)` returns a 44kb file; `html_vignette` returns 6.1kb; `prettydoc::html_pretty` returns 63.7kb (you need to install the [**prettydoc**](https://github.com/yixuan/prettydoc) package). If you want a "flashy" style, I think **prettydoc** has achieved a great balance between styles and file sizes; otherwise you have to bear with those "vanilla" styles.

Comment: Thank you Yihui, appreciate the time taken to research and respond to my question.  I have saved this away in my 'solutions' file :).

Answer (score 0):

A more recent approach would be using prettydoc package. Refer to https://github.com/yixuan/prettydoc 
for more information.

Comment: This is not an answer but a comment please visit and check [how to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).