# modalDialog doesn't work when includeHTML (generated with knitr) used

Tags: r, shiny, modal-dialog, knitr

I'm trying to insert some additional content to the modalDialog in shiny with includeHTML.
The first time everything goes well and button works. But on the second click my button doesn't work.
If I delete includeHTML, everything works well.

```
showModal(
        modalDialog(size = "m",
                    title = NULL,
                    includeHTML("data/article.html"), # created with knitr from Rmd
                    tagList(
                      fluidRow(
                        column(12,actionButton(inputId = "find",
                                               style="background-color: #bb7879; color:#FFFFFF; width:50%",
                                               "Click"),align="center")
                      )),
                    footer = NULL,
                    easyClose = T
        )
      )
```

Also when I use `onclick("find")` instead of `observeEvent(input$find,{...})` button began to work but modalDialog can't be closed with `removeModal` in that case.

UPD: After deleting some big parts of HTML like `script src="data:application/javascript;base64,LyohIGpRdWV...`, it works. So the problem can be in the `knitr` and `shiny` compatibility

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: I think this may be a round about way of asking how to knit an rmd to HTML with minimal javascript ; so try - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29927401/11726436

Comment: Yes, it is solution for my problem, thank you! Though it would be great to use `theme` yet.